# the \expanded primitive is not provided by your TeX engine, listofitems v1.63 cannot work: loading listofitems v1.61

Tags: pdftex, command-line, engine

### Scenario

I am compiling a latex document from python 3.6 in Anaconda 4.8.2 on a Windows 10 Pro N device. To do so, I created a python 3.6 environment in Anaconda Prompt, installed miktex in anaconda with command:

```
conda install -c conda-forge miktex
```

And execute the following python code with:

```
def create_pdfV3(self, input_filename, output_filename):
        argList = [
            'pdflatex',   # Or maybe 'C:\\Program Files\\MikTex\\miktex\\bin\\latex.exe
            '-output-format=pdf',
            '-job-name=' + output_filename,
            input_filename,
            '-enable-installer']
        print(f'argList={argList}')
        process = subprocess.Popen(argList)
```

Which returns the following error:

```
(C:\Users\someuser\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\listofitems\listofitems.sty
(C:\Users\someuser\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\listofitems\listofitems.tex

! Package listofitems Error: the \expanded primitive is not provided by your Te
X engine, listofitems v1.63 cannot work: loading listofitems v1.61.

See the listofitems package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.67    {\input listofitemsold.tex\relax\endinput}
                                                %
?
```

From what I understand from the answer in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/493851/listofitems-error-the-expanded-primitive-is-not-provided-by-your-tex-engine) the error is caused because the TEX engine that is used to compile the `main.tex` is not updated to include the `\expanded` primitive.

The version used for pdflatex as found by executing command `pdflatex --version` manually in the python 3.6 environment of Anaconda prompt, yields:

```
pdflatex --version
MiKTeX-pdfTeX 2.9.6668 (1.40.19) (MiKTeX 2.9.6730)
Copyright (C) 1982 D. E. Knuth, (C) 1996-2018 Han The Thanh
TeX is a trademark of the American Mathematical Society.
using bzip2 version 1.0.6, 6-Sept-2010
compiled with curl version 7.56.1; using libcurl/7.56.1 WinSSL
compiled with expat version 2.2; using expat_2.2.0
compiled with jpeg version 9.2
compiled with liblzma version 50020032; using 50020032
compiled with libpng version 1.6.34; using 1.6.34
compiled with libressl version LibreSSL 2.5.3; using LibreSSL 2.5.3
compiled with MiKTeX Application Framework version 2.6636; using 2.6636
compiled with MiKTeX Core version 7.6745; using 7.6745
compiled with MiKTeX Archive Extractor version 1.6300; using 1.6300
compiled with MiKTeX Package Manager version 3.6727; using 3.6727
compiled with poppler version 0.60.1
compiled with uriparser version 0.8.4
compiled with zlib version 1.2.11; using 1.2.11
```

### Question

How can switch the TEX engine to enable compiling with the `\expanded` primitive?

Comment: How old is your miktex? In  a current miktex there should be no problem. \expanded is supported.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thank you for your question, the output of `pdflatex --version` is included in the question. As an explicit answer to your question I would give: `MiKTeX-pdfTeX 2.9.6668 (1.40.19) (MiKTeX 2.9.6730)`.

Comment: well 2018 is too old. \expanded was added later. I have `MiKTeX-pdfTeX 4.0.1 (MiKTeX 20.7)` with a copyright mentioning 2020: 1996-2020 Hàn Thế Thành

Comment: I have the same problem. My miktex has been correctly updated but the problem remained.