# How to solve the package pgfkeys Error the code below on Texmaker when using tikz and pgfplots packages?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[gray, thick] (-1,2) -- (2,-4);
\draw[gray, thick] (-1,-1) -- (2,2);
\filldraw[black] (0,0) circle (2pt) node[anchor=west]{Intersection point};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

After compiling this code I get the following error that I'm unable to fix:

> ! Package pgfkeys Error: PGF requires the \expanded
> primitive.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your provided code compiles correctly. So what is your error?

Comment: I took a liberty and shorten your question title. Please show us errors , if you got any with your code example!

Comment: Could you give the full log for your example file?

Comment: It seems the TeX distribution you are using is very old an outdated. `\expanded` has been introduced with all TeX engines in TeX Live (and AFAIK also in MiKTeX) in 2019. So if you get this error, you should update your TeX distribution. Alternatively you could try LuaLaTeX, that provides `\expanded` even longer.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/559528/277964 https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/493851/277964